# Highcharts Series data as JSON doesn't render

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I had a 'spline' HighChart working but wanted to add some more data to the tooltip so wish to use the JSON object with `x` and `y` syntax to be able to further populate this object

Originally I was using series in the format:

```
{
  name: 'Series 1',
  data: [[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]
}
```

This worked fine, however changing it to:

```
{
  name: 'Series 1',
  data: [{x: xVal, y: yVal},{x: xVal, y: yVal},{x: xVal, y: yVal}]
}
```

Has stopped my chart working. Using a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xbL65gqn/ this syntax appears to be valid. What could cause it to not work?

For reference heres my highcharts config:

```
{
chart: {
  type: 'spline',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  style: {
    color: FONT_COLOR
  }
},
credits: { enabled: false },
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    marker: { enabled: false }
  }
},
legend: { enabled: false },
series: series,
title: {
  text: '',
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: FONT_COLOR
    }
  }
},
tooltip: {
  crosshairs: {
    dashStyle: 'solid'
  }
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: FONT_COLOR
    }
  }
},
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'Uplift',
    textAlign: 'right',
    rotation: 0,
    style: {
      color: FONT_COLOR
    },
    y: -174,
    x: 34
  },
  max: maxLabel,
  min: -maxLabel,
  showLastLabel: false,
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      return this.value + '%'
    },
    style: {
      color: FONT_COLOR
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How many points do you load to the chart? If more than 1000, it is probably caused by turboThreshold https://jsfiddle.net/xbL65gqn/1/ If it is caused by turboThreshold, disable by setting it to 0 (0 or a value which is bigger than number of the points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. When calculating the `min` and `max` on the `y` axis I was using the series data to find them by getting `seriesData[1]` (the `y` coord) and didn't account for this when changing the structure to the JSON object

Thus my `min` and `max` on the `y` axis were `NaN`